# How to export data form one keyspace to another in cassandra on one node?

Tags: export, backup, cassandra

I have keyspace that is for dev project and i need to export data from it to another keyspace that is for production project.
The both keyspaces is on one cluster.
How can i do that?

Comment: [link](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/operations/backup_restore) doesnt works, i copied snapshot files but cassandra doesn't see them, even as column families

Comment: production keyspace has the same schema as dev project. Keyspace is just created and has empty folders.

Comment: json2sstable requires an *.db file, but folders is empty. where i need to get it? to make some test data, save it, restart cassandra, that delete it?

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you running?